# Ubuntu server 14.04 and systemd-udevd process with high CPU usage

Tags: 14.04, udev, systemd

After upgrading from Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 to Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server version, I observed a huge usage of CPU (~ 90%) by **systemd-udevd** processes (3).

Running `udevadm monitor` display continuously following outputs, showing that it always try to add / remove devices :

```
UDEV  [19081.096929] remove   /devices/virtual/block/md0 (block)
UDEV  [19081.108949] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/9:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[19081.115486] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/9:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[19081.115803] add      /devices/virtual/block/md0 (block)
KERNEL[19081.116533] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/9:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[19081.116834] remove   /devices/virtual/block/md0 (block)
```

I'm not familiar with all this and I would appreciate to understand what's happening and how to stop that.

How can I fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem on Mint 17.3 Rosa. To solve it, when my pc is idle : - I open up terminal, - login as SU, - use Top command and see PID of systemd, - and i kill it. CPU back to normal and Ram usage went low. Of course my desktop still stable, i can use my desktop normally after that operation. sorry for my bad english.